# ngrx url as single source of truth in filtering feature

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm developing feature where you can filter entities by different criteria. Selected criteria reflects in UI filters and chips. The idea is to store filters in URL.

The flow of application goes like:

```
  => queryParams are parsed and mapped to filters
  => filters are stored in store 
    => chips are calculated based on filters
    => api call is triggered to fetch data
```

When UI event happens ngrx/effect handles it, eg. we want to remove a filter by clicking on a chip. Effect method takes clicked chip and current state then calculate queryParams from it and triggers navigation with new queryParams. Last element of effect pipe looks like:

```
const filters = selectFilters(storeState);
filter.removeValue(value);
return this.router.navigate(['some route'], {
  queryParams: filters.toQueryParams()
});
```

It seems like my effect is doing some kind of state managment which raise my eyebrow.

I would be very grateful for validation of this approach.